# Does the Canon EOS Rebel T5/1200D have any dust related problems?

Tags: canon, sensor, cleaning, dust

I’m planning on purchasing the Canon EOS Rebel T5/1200D very soon. It’s the only DSLR that fits my budget (other one is the Nikon D3100 which I don't plan to get).

I like everything about the camera except that it does not have any Sensor Cleaning System. I’ve read that the cleaning system does effectively reduce the amount of dust on the sensor, but since the Rebel T5 does not have any cleaning mechanism, I guess there will be some issues related to dust gathering on the sensor.

Also since the Rebel T5/1200D is a relatively new camera, there aren’t that many users sharing experiences with this issue, so I’m not able to get an idea of whether the Rebel T5 has or will get the dust problem.

My question is, does anyone with a DSLR that does not have built in cleaning system face any kind of dust related problem? Even the Canon EOS Rebel T3/1100D didn’t had the cleaning system. So Rebel T3/1100D users, are you facing such issues?

Comment: Canon has continued the practice of eliminating the Auto Sensor Cleaning System on the most basic DSLRs. The following Canon EOS DSLRs do NOT have built-in Dust-Reduction. (automatic sensor cleaning) : T3/1100D, T5/1200D, T6/1300D, T7/2000D, and T100/4000D.

Answer (score 4):

No, this isn't a huge deal.

Aside from the 1x00D series, other Canon camera models that did not have the sensor-shake/cleaning feature include: 1Ds, 1DsMkII, 1D, 1DMkII, 5D (classic), 10D, 20D, 30D, 300D (Rebel), and 350D (XT).

I shot with the 350D (it was my first dSLR) for four years, I changed lenses like a mad thing, often forgetting (gasp! horror!) to turn the camera off when I did so.  I wasn't particularly careful when I did so, and I never had to do more than use [a bulb blower](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Giottos-Rocket-Air-Blower-Review.aspx) to clean dust off the sensor.  But I live in a very dry climate, so I rarely get the "welded on" dust issue that someone who lives where the humidity is high may suffer, and I only occasionally shoot landscapes where I'm stopping the lens down to the point where the dust is more evident.

Remember, too, that the mirrorbox assembly is covering your sensor when you change a lens.

The worst that can happen, though, is dust ends up on the sensor, and you have to clean it. And there are any number of tools and tutorials on how to do this easily and safely (I like [Lens Rentals's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iRW9AmDPqr0), but to each their own).  It is a task you can perform yourself, that you do not have to go to a service center to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the Rebel T5 for over a year. I have cleaned it myself and it's a pain I tell you! My first Rebel had a self-cleaning function. This is the only thing I don't like about the T5.  Dust gathers up a lot if you are changing lenses frequently.

Answer (score 0):

There is a menu setting for manual cleaning. To get to it, you have to take the setting off of Scene Intelligent Auto. Put it on, for example Program AE, then go to menu and you will find Clean Manually.

Answer (score -1):

I've had mine 5 months now and there is a horrible issue with dust on the sensor. It costs around $100 to get it cleaned up here...

Comment: Have you owned other cameras?  Is the 1200D worse than the others with respect to dust?

Comment: Or, clean it yourself for much less than that.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with spots on photos. Went to my local camera shop, and was told it was cheaper to do myself than have it cleaned for $80-100. I bought a kit for $35 and had no issues. Because there is no menu setting on the T5 to clean the sensor, I set my shutter speed to "bulb" and held the shutter button down while I cleaned the sensor. Took less than 2 minutes, and dust particles are gone!